Read evaluated values of a plugin extension after sync, from a Android Studio plugin
In the app module of an Android Studio project, there is a plugin extension like this:
// aFunction that returns an string

SomePlugin{
   someValue aFunction()
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.qtquickview_java'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.qtquickview_java"
        minSdk 28
// ... rest of the file

aFunction() gets called during sync in Android Studio. It seems that the returning value is cached somewhere on disk or memory. I want to read the evaluated value of SomePlugin.someValue from an Android Studio (IntelliJ) plugin.
